# Probability that the number of heads is coprime with the number of throws

Tags: probability, number-theory

Let's throw a coin $n$ times. Say that we have obtained heads $k$ times and tails $n-k$ times. I'm interested in the probability that the number of heads is coprime with the total number of throws. Obviously, this probability is described by the formula
$$
P=\sum_{\substack{0<k<n,\\gcd(k, n)=1}}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k},
$$
where $p\in(0, 1)$ is a probability of throwing heads.

**The question.**
Is it true that this sum is lower bounded by some positive constant for all integers $n > 1$?

**My thoughts.** I think that it should be true. Take $p=1/2$ for simplicity. Some computer calculations suggest that $P\ge 0.1875$, and this bound is achieved for $n=6$. But I don't know how to prove it.

It's also easy to show that $P\ge c n^{-1/2}$ for some constant $c$ because we can always find such number $k$, which is coprime with $n$ and close to $n/2$. But this bound is too weak.

**Update.**
[@donaastor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/251847/donaastor) made some interesting comments below and convinced me that for all constant $p$ the lower limit of the probability equals 0. Also, further computer calculations for $p=1/2$ showed that the probability for $n=30030$ is lower than for n=6 and equals $\approx 0.1828$.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem indeed! Do you know about asymptotic lower bound on $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$? It isn't bounded by a constant but another slowly decreasing function. So, I believe that your function is not bounded by a constant as well, but some related slowly decreasing function.

Comment: @donaastor I calculated this probability for all $n<10^4$, and the minimum is achieved for $n=6$. I understand that this is a weak argument. You made a good point. So, maybe you are right and I'm wrong. But then it would be even more interesting to obtain a good lower bound!

Comment: Maybe you want to study analytic number theory, specifically to read about Dirichlet character and Dirichlet series and ordinary generating functions and then try to express your number as a coefficient in some analytic function. There is plenty of theorems on asymtotics of these coefficients.

Comment: Interesting question.  To me, it's not really about $\frac {\varphi(n)}n$  Rather, it concerns the numbers near $\frac n2$. Or $np$ in general. You want a lot of those to have factors in common with $n$, doesn't really matter what happens far from that strip.

Comment: You see, when you draw a pattern of whether a number is coprime or not with a given number, then a pattern for a power of 6 is just a repeated pattern of pattern for 6. Now, take some number $n$ with low ratio of $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$ and take some big power of it, say $n^n$. The pattern for $n^n$ will be "uniformly" spread and the peak of the binomial distribution is in the middle $\sqrt{n^n}$ elements which covers a lot of periods of your pattern, So I believe that in that case the total probability will be very close to $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$.

Comment: Perhaps you should look for  Primorial numbers https://oeis.org/A002110

Comment: I see that you mentioned me in the question body :) Just to add, you can be sure that the lower limit is 0 for any $p$. That's because for any $p$ (when taken as a constant) the size of the peak will be of order $\sqrt{n}$. See this theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem. The deviation here is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.

Comment: Thank you). I think that you have already answered my question, but I don't know how to mark it, since you wrote everything in the comments)

Answer (score 4):

If we define $P_d$ as the sum over $k$ multiples of $d$, one can see that

$$ P_{coprime} = \sum_{d \mid n } \mu(d) P_d $$

Where $\mu$ is the Moebius function. This is sophisticated way of expressing an inclusion-exclusion: first you put all terms via $P_1$; then you subtract all stuff that have a prime in common with $n$ via $-P_q$ for q prime; then you have to add back things that are multiple of two primes... Moebius function implements this in a neat way. Now $P_d$ is a bit easier to describe.  Let

$$F_n(z) = (pz + 1-p) ^n$$

his is a polynomial in $z$ which has exactly the terms of your summation in each degree: in particular $F_n(1) =1$ is the total probability. This is also called the generating function of the distribution.

If you average on d-th roots of unity $\zeta_d$ you will get rid of terms which are not divisible by d: this is called root of unity sieve technique. Now let $\zeta$ by a primitive $n$-th root of unity. We have that $\zeta^{nk/d} $ for $k=1, \ldots, d$ enumerates all the d-roots of unity. Thus

$$ P_d = \frac{1}{d} \left ( \sum_{k=1}^d (p \zeta^{nk/d} + 1-p) ^n \right ) $$

Plugging this into $P_{coprime}$ yields

$$ P_{coprime} = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \frac{1}{d} \left ( \sum_{k=1}^d (p \zeta^{nk/d} + 1-p) ^n \right ) $$

We want to exchange this summation in terms of when a given root of unity appears. A power $( \ldots )^n $ containing the root $\omega = \zeta^r$ appears for $r=nk/d$ with a coefficient of $\mu(d) /d$ in front. In particular, it appears exactly when $n/d \mid r$. Changing variable $d' = n/d$ we can thus write

$$ P_{coprime} = \sum_{r=1}^n (p \zeta^r + 1-p) ^n \sum_{d' \mid r} \mu(d') \frac{1}{d'}  = \sum_{r=1}^n (p\zeta^r + 1-p)^n \frac{\varphi(r)}{r} = \sum_{r=1}^n (1+ p(\zeta^r-1))^n \frac{\varphi(r)}{r} $$

For $p << 1$ we get

$$ \simeq \sum_{r=1}^n (1+np(\zeta^r-1)) \frac{\varphi(r)}{r} $$

And I think we can approximate this number by its real part, because it is close in norm to $P_{coprime}$ which is real. This we get

$$\simeq \sum_{r=1}^n (1+np(\cos(2\pi r/n) -1)) \frac{\varphi(r)}{r} = (1-np) \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{\varphi(r)}{r} +np \sum_{r=1}^n \cos(2\pi r/n) \frac{\varphi(r)}{r} $$

Comment: This is a nice answer. Can you maybe define all the numbers that you use, such as $P_{coprime}$, more clearly, please. I don't quite get what you are evaluating and I can't guess so easily what you meant to say. Naturally, I expect that $P_{coprime}$ is what Ilya was asking for, but then your result is greater than $1$? So you were doing something else, but I don't see what.

Comment: Yes, $P_{coprime}$ is the $P$ asked by OP. I put an index to distinguish better from other probabilities. I am still left with estimating the last sum; happy if you want to contribute. I was wrong before, I implicitly used the triangle inequality in the wrong direction (indeed, a probability growing linearly with n is weird...). Now the dependence on $n$ should cancel.

Comment: I spotted the error, gonna correct tomorrow :)

Comment: Nice, I might get involved tomorrow too and see if I can "contribute" anyhow :)